# Can't find number of occurrences of a value in a column of a csv file with R

Tags: r, csv

I have multiple large csv files which all have identical columns. I read them into a list called listFinal.data in R. I need to count up the number of occurrences of different items that occur in some of the columns. For instance, there is a column called "Biological.Stage". Values in that column can be "none", "incubation", "symptomatic" or "convalescence". I need to count up how many times each of these different stages occurs. This works fine. However, I have another column called "Incapacitation.Status" where the values can be "Not Incapacitated" or "Incapacitated". I need to count up how many times each of those occur as well. I use the same method, but I get an error which says:

```
Error in incapacitated_count[[l]] <- nrow(listFinal.data[[l]][listFinal.data[[l]]$Incapacitation.Status ==  : object 'incapacitated_count' not found
```

This doesn't seem that difficult, but I have been going round and round all day and can't make this work. Can someone please point out my error before I go crazy?

I edited my post to show my code more completely, not just the loop in question as was suggested by one of the kind people that responded to try to help me. I was trying to avoid posting too much of my code because I know it is probably not very good. Please keep in mind I am self taught and don't do a lot of coding.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(rlist)
library(magrittr)
library(DT)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
 

options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 200*1024^2)

wd <<- choose.dir(caption = "Select top level folder where your data is located")
setwd(wd)

#List the full path and filename of all files in the working directory and sub-directories that starts
#with "BioModel_" and ends with ".csv"
out_files <- list.files(pattern = "^BioModel(.*)csv$", recursive = TRUE)

# create an empty list that will serve as a container to receive the incoming files
list.data<-list()
listForceFinal.data<-list()
listForceInitial.data<-list()
outputInitial.data<-list()
listOcularFinal.data<-list()
listInhalationFinal.data<-list()
listSurfaceFinal.data<-list()
listChemFinal.data<-list()
listBioFinal<-list()
listFatalities.data<-list()
listFinal.data<-list()
listContaminatedVeh.data<-list()
none_count<-list()
minor_count<-list()
major_count<-list()
lethal_count<-list()
incubation_count<-list()
symptomatic_count<-list()
convalescence_count<-list()
incubation_count<-list()
vehicle_count<-list()
incapacitation_count<-list()
# 
 num_reps <- length(out_files)

# create a loop to read in your data

for (i in 1:length(out_files))
{
  list.data[[i]]<-read.csv(out_files[i], check.names = TRUE)
}

# # create a loop to get the final contamination level and remove all others
for (h in 1:length(list.data))
  listFinal.data[[h]] <- list.data[[h]] %>%
  group_by(Actor.ID, Actor.Name) %>%
  slice(n())

output <- plyr::ldply(listFinal.data, function(x) x %>%
  group_by(Entity.Type) %>%
  summarise(n=n()))

listContaminatedVeh.data <- output %>%
  filter(Entity.Type != "Lifeform") %>%
  group_by(Entity.Type) %>%
  summarise(Mean.Final = mean(n)) %>%
  rename("Platform Type" = Entity.Type, Mean = Mean.Final)

#Contaminated Entities

#create a loop to sum up the total number of contaminated and incapacitated entities in each rep
for (l in 1:length(listFinal.data)){
  incubation_count[[l]] <- nrow(listFinal.data[[l]][listFinal.data[[l]]$Biological.Stage == "incubation",])
  symptomatic_count[[l]] <- nrow(listFinal.data[[l]][listFinal.data[[l]]$Biological.Stage == "symptomatic",])
  convalescence_count[[l]] <- nrow(listFinal.data[[l]][listFinal.data[[l]]$Biological.Stage == "convalescence",])
  incapacitated_count[[l]] <- nrow(listFinal.data[[l]][listFinal.data[[l]]$Incapacitation.Status == "Incapacitated",])
}

# calculate the average number of entities with biological contamination / incapacitation across all reps
result.incubationAvg <- mean(as.numeric(incubation_count))
result.incubationAvg <- round(result.incubationAvg)

result.symptomaticAvg <- mean(as.numeric(symptomatic_count))
result.symptomaticAvg <- round(result.symptomaticAvg)

result.convalescenceAvg <- mean(as.numeric(convalescence_count))
result.convalescenceAvg <- round(result.convalescenceAvg)

result.incapacitationAvg <- mean(as.numeric(incapacitation_count))
result.incapacitationAvg <- round(result.incapacitationAvg)
```

And here is an condensed version of my data file. It's a large file, so I removed columns that don't pertain to the issue and only included a small sample of rows.

```
df <- read.table(text = "
Time Stamp,Biological Stage,Contaminant Type,Incapacitation Status,Concentration of Agent  
13206478,symptomatic,biological,Incapacitated,8.38E-05  
13087148,none,biological,Not Incapacitated,0  
12966365,none,biological,Not Incapacitated,0  
13207078,none,biological,Not Incapacitated,8.38E-05  
", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

Comment: one comment: instead of keeping your dataframes in a list, if they're all just segments of the same data, you can combine them using `bind_rows()` or `map_dfr()` or something similar 

Comment: I definitely consider myself to be an R newbie, so I apologize for any uninformed sounding comments, but each csv file is output from a simulation, so I will be finding means etc across all of the replications, so I need to keep the files separated. Even these counts for total incapacitations and individuals in each biological stage will be averaged across all the reps. That was why I was using a list and trying to implement an array to keep them separate. Definitely might not be the best approach, but the only one that I could think of.

Comment: if you're averaging across all dataframes in the list, then I would put them all into one dataframe (maybe with a column for the simulation #) but you do you ✌️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the suggestions from everyone and come up with something that works for the way that I have my data arranged in a list of dataframes. I appreciate everyone's help, because I don't believe that I would have figured it out without it. I wasn't really understanding the way that the data was arranged and how to access it, but you all helped me to see that and that I needed to use the apply functions.

For completeness, this is the code that is working for me:

```
incapacitation_count <- plyr::ldply(listFinal.data, function(x) x %>%
                             group_by(Incapacitation.Status) %>%
                             summarise(n=n()))
listIncapStat.data <- incapacitation_count %>%
group_by(Incapacitation.Status) %>%
summarise(Mean.Final = mean(n)) %>%
rename("Incapacitation Status" = Incapacitation.Status, Mean = Mean.Final)
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution.  FYI - `count(Incapacitation.Status)` is roughly equivalent to `group_by(Incapacitation.Status) %>% summarise(n=n()))` if that's all you're doing.  See `?dplyr::count` for details.  You should probably mark this as your answer if you're satisfied and close it out of the queue.

Comment: ScottyJ, thanks for the info. I'm definitely still learning!

Answer (score 0):

I find `dplyr` and `tidyr` (included in `tidyverse`) handy for data wrangling in a way that is both concise and legible. Here, I `count` how many times different values appear in `Biological.Stage`, and then I `complete` the count table to include specified values that might or might not have been included in the data. You could also do this with base R with factors and `table`, but this looks simpler to me.

```
library(tidyverse)
df |> 
  count(Biological.Stage) |>
  complete(Biological.Stage = c("none", "incubation", "symptomatic", "convalescence"), 
           fill = list(n = 0))


# A tibble: 4 × 2
  Biological.Stage     n
  <chr>            <int>
1 convalescence        0
2 incubation           0
3 none                 3
4 symptomatic          1
```

Or if the non-present values aren't important to count, you could do all the columns at once with:

```
df |>
  pivot_longer(Biological.Stage:Incapacitation.Status) |>
  count(name, value)

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  name                  value                 n
  <chr>                 <chr>             <int>
1 Biological.Stage      none                  3
2 Biological.Stage      symptomatic           1
3 Contaminant.Type      biological            4
4 Incapacitation.Status Incapacitated         1
5 Incapacitation.Status Not Incapacitated     3
```

Comment: I am using both the dplyr and tidyverse libraries, but I am getting an error with the complete function:
Error in complete(., Biological.Stage = c("none", "incubation", "symptomatic",  : 
  could not find function "complete"

Comment: @GAdams, if you have `library(tidyverse)` loaded, then `help("complete", package = tidyr)`, or `?complete`  (it's part of `tidyr`)

Answer (score 0):

This first part is just to generate data to the point I think your question is starting at:

### Getting to `listFinal.data` starting point

```
Biological.State <- sample(c("none", "incubation", "symptomatic", "convalescence"), 
                                                     size = 1000, 
                                                     replace = TRUE)

Incapacitation.Status <- sample(c("Not Incapacitated", "Incapacitated"),
                                                                size = 1000,
                                                                replace = TRUE)

df_start <- data.frame(Biological.State, Incapacitation.Status)

chunk <- 50
n <- nrow(df_start)
r <- rep(1:ceiling(n/chunk), each = chunk)[1:n]
listFinal.data <- split(df_start, r)
```

Everything above is just me creating `listFinal.data` which is like 20 csv files that you've pulled into that list.

### Solution

```
library(tidyverse)

df_FinalData <- bind_rows(listFinal.data) # Takes all the individual list elements and puts them in a single dataframe (again)

> head(df_FinalData)
  Biological.State Incapacitation.Status
1       incubation     Not Incapacitated
2             none         Incapacitated
3    convalescence         Incapacitated
4    convalescence     Not Incapacitated
5      symptomatic     Not Incapacitated
6       incubation         Incapacitated

> df_FinalData %>% count(Incapacitation.Status)

  Incapacitation.Status   n
1         Incapacitated 502
2     Not Incapacitated 498

> df_FinalData %>% count(Biological.State)

  Biological.State   n
1    convalescence 236
2       incubation 242
3             none 281
4      symptomatic 241
```

Comment: I get an error when I try to create the dataframe and I have no idea what it is telling me:
Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `..1$Secondary` <logical> and `..2$Secondary` <character>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @GAdams, I think you need to post your code up in your question.  Looks like you didn't set your datatypes when you read in your .csv files, so you won't be able to `bind_rows()` as you would if they files were read in consistently.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df |> 
  mutate(Biological.Stage = factor(Biological.Stage, levels = c("none", "incubation", "symptomatic", "convalescence")),
          Incapacitation.Status =  Incapacitation.Status  == "Incapacitated") # if you only have two categories, which are basically just true or false, you may as well use TRUE and FALSE and get it over with

# to get the frequency for each column individually:
map(df, ~table(.x))
```